# How to use Google Analytics in Progressive Web Apps that may be offline?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

My site is a progressive web app (single page / SPA) that works offline.

I'd like to use Google Analytics but aren't sure how to report events in this case, especially since the device may be offline.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

One strategy is to record analytics events, store them locally, and replay them when online: [Service Workers in Production](https://developers.google.com/web/showcase/case-study/service-workers-iowa) has detailed discussion on that and some source code - search for *Offline Google Analytics* section.

Answer (score 4):

There's a new library that automates this process for you. The "[Offline Google Analytics Made Easy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/offline-google-analytics?hl=en)" article has more details, but the code boils down to a `npm install --save-dev sw-offline-google-analytics` followed by the following in your service worker JavaScript:

```
importScripts('path/to/offline-google-analytics-import.js');
goog.offlineGoogleAnalytics.initialize();
```

The code itself is a modified version of what we described earlier in that "[Service Workers in Production](https://developers.google.com/web/showcase/2015/service-workers-iowa)" article.